# How to enable BITS Peercaching?

Tags: windows, group-policy, bits

Beyond the obvious of setting the GPO to "enabled".

`bitsadmin /peercaching /getconfigurationflags`

```
Peercaching configuration flags:
         Enable download from peers      :false
         Enable serving to peers         :false
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: PeerCaching was effectively removed in Windows 7 and has been replaced by BranchCache.

> Note  Starting with Windows 7, the BITS 3.0 peer caching model is
>   deprecated. If BITS 4.0 is installed, the BITS 3.0 peer caching model
>   is unavailable.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa964314%28v=vs.85%29.aspx